# How to use c# to get request url host in multiple domain in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, url-rewriting

I have an ASP.NET web app deployed to domain www.client1.com. One rewrite rule is added to it in IIS manager to make it support multiple hosts. Now both following urls can access it.

http://www.client1.com/app

http://www.client2.com/app

in c#, "Request.Url.Authority" always returns "www.client1.com" when visiting both above urls. Is it possible to get "www.client2.com" when visiting http://www.client2.com/app?

Comment: I don't think you need rewrite rule - just change binding to allow all incoming urls... I strongly suspect that you rewrite all incoming hosts as coming from www.client1.com...

Comment: I would replace rewrite rule with additional binding (see here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731692(v=ws.10).aspx). You would then be able to see host name in your code